# What is a "time of kingdom's decree"

Tags: halacha, halacha-theory, politics-government, martyr

The gemara in [Sanhedrin 74](http://www.hebrewbooks.org/shas.aspx?mesechta=24&daf=74&format=pdf) talks about a time of oppression, during which even for "light mitzvot" one must die.

What exactly constitutes such a time? Is it any time when the government makes a decision that will impact Jews specifically, or is there more to it?

Sources appreciated.